# Facebook app - deep link for new app user

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-apps

### Short version

I have a facebook iframe app as a page tab on a fan page. The app collects entries for a contest. It lists the entries and also has a page for showing a single entry. I want to be able to link to the single-entry page - I have this working using the `app_data` parameter, but only if the user has used the app before. This does not work for a new user who has to add the app (log in).

### Long version

So far I've managed to get this partially working by linking to

```
http://facebook.com/pages/<myPageName>/<myPageId>?sk=app_<myAppID>&app_data=<myUrlEncodedJsonData>
```

The `app_data` parameter is passed on to my application's iframe by facebook and I can then process it server-side to redirect the user to the appropriate subpage. All seems to work well... but only if I had logged into the application before trying to access the deep-linked content.

If I try to deep link to the single-entry page and don't have the application installed yet (scenario: I'm a friend of a contestant and I've been encouraged to vote for his entry, I haven't used the app yet), then, after logging in, I'm on the index page of my app, and that is not what I'm after.

I'm using PHP facebook SDK to obtain a loginUrl like this:

```
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('canvas' => 1,'fbconnect' => 0, 'scope' => 'email,publish_stream,offline_access,user_likes,publish_actions', 'next' => $canvasPage));
```

where `$canvasPage` is the full URL of the app on my server, `$loginURL` is where I redirect the user if I detect he is not logged in my application.

What should I change to be able to direct new users straight to specific content (subpage) within my app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I used session to store where the user wants to get initially, then redirect him to the login page, and when he/she's back, session is read to redirect the user to the final destination.