# What is the best way to link into the frame of Facebook application?

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, redirect

I have a pure iframe Facebook app in PHP. By being pure I want to say it has no meaning to approach it's in-iframe URLs directly. If someone accidentaly approached (e.g. by opening a link from the inside of app in a new tab) URL of the app outside of iframe, my app can recognize it by JavaScript and redirects to it's version in iframe.

However, my desired behavior is to send the user to the same URL he wanted to approach, only inside Facebook platform iframe. Example:

- User goes to: http://app.myserver.com/pages/help/
- My app redirects to: https://apps.facebook.com/my-awesome-app/, in iframe is initial page http://app.myserver.com/
- Where I'd like to redirect: https://apps.facebook.com/my-awesome-app/, in iframe is requested page http://app.myserver.com/pages/help/

What would be the best solution in your opinion? I thought about sessions, do they have any drawbacks? I can save original location and start redirect to iframe, then find out what was the location and redirect to that page inside the iframe. How can I ensure the user who is being redirected doesn't interrupt the process and doesn't cause any unpredictible redirects later due to the saved but not resolved one? What about user having multiple tabs with my app? Tabs could steal redirects one from the another...

Answer (score 1):

For example, redirect user to https://apps.facebook.com/my-awesome-app/?page=help and analyze query in your application(or use httpd rewrite rules).

Comment: AFAIK the parameters will not be included in the URL of the iframe that Facebook will create for the app. The only exception to this rule is the `app_data` parameter - again, AFAIK.

Comment: You are not right. I just checked and it works for me.

I've added following to my test page
   alert(document.location.search);

Comment: That is interesting. Does this get the query string from the iframe or the parent page? Also, were you able to get the parameter server-side?

Comment: Also, params are present in referrer header  


   alert(document.referrer);

Comment: Yes, params are present on server side as well. I wasn't able to find related documentation so maybe bububaba can say why on his opinion parameters are not being passed.

Comment: Well, I'm pretty sure they weren't passed when I was creating an app a few months ago. I will have to dig into it again to re-check.

Comment: BTW, in that article (Facebook app - deep link for new app user) key difference is that user is NEW i.e. he's redirected to login page and as result parameters are lost. Your use-case is a bit different.

Comment: Yes, I know that, but it was an issue on top of the original problem of redirecting user. I posted it as it contains the answer to this problem in the question. Which may not be the optimal answer, as I'm investigating your findings now.

Comment: OK, I dug up the old app. The main issue seems to be that the app is a `Page Tab` app, not an `App on Facebook`. Maybe this is the source of differences. The other issue is that I mixed up the presence of `app_data` parameter - it is NOT passed on as a normal parameter, it is added however to the `signed request` that your app gets from Facebook. I could not obtain any other parameters, neither server-side nor client-side.

Comment: Thank you guys for clarifying the options, even the discussion about Page Tabs was interesting. I'll try it as soon as I am back to this issue and if it works, I'll mark this answer as the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

The below are my findings with respect to `Page Tab` apps. It may not be true at all for `App on Facebook` apps.

Normally, Facebook will not pass on query string parameters to the URL of your iframe, so you can't go the `facebook.com/.../my_app?where=help&page=2` way.

It will however pass on the `app_data` paramater inside the signed request (it is the only exception to the rule AFAIK). But this leaves you with only one parameter to play with. You can counter that, by making it a url-encoded JSON object, containing in fact many variables. Example:

`facebook.com/.../my_app?app_data=%7bwhere%3a+%22help%22%2c+page%3a+2%7d`

Which on the server side you receive by `json_decode($signedRequest['app_data'])` and receiving

```
array(
    'where' => 'page',
    'page' => 2
)
```

From here on, it is up to you to perform the redirects. You won't have to use sessions, unless your user is not logged in to facebook and / or your app. Then you'd have to complicate this a little. My solution was to use sessions for the not-logged-in scenario: [Facebook app - deep link for new app user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8445495/facebook-app-deep-link-for-new-app-user)